# '0' characters appering within string values when writing to a text file

Tags: python, text

I am creating Python code in which string values made by dividing two values are to be saved to a .txt file. When the file is written, zero (0) characters appear within the values. Here is the relevent part of the code:

```
PlayerOneSkill = str(PlayerOneSkill)
PlayerOneStrength = str(PlayerOneStrength)
PlayerTwoSkill = str(PlayerTwoSkill)
PlayerTwoStrength = str(PlayerTwoStrength)
P1SkillMod = str(P1SkillRoll12/P1SkillRoll4)
P1StrengthMod = str(P1StrengthRoll12/P1StrengthRoll4)
P2SkillMod = str(P2SkillRoll12/P2SkillRoll4)
P2StrengthMod = str(P2StrengthRoll12/P2StrengthRoll4)

f = file ("Attribute.txt","w")
f.write ("P1 skill is " + PlayerOneSkill + P1SkillMod)
f.write ("P1 strength is " + PlayerOneStrength + P1StrengthMod)
f.write ("P2 skill is " + PlayerTwoSkill + P2SkillMod)
f.write ("P2 strength is " + PlayerTwoStrength + P2StrengthMod)
f.close()
```

Say the player one attributes were 12 and 16, and the player two attributes were 10 and 11, the text file would read:

```
P1 skill is 102P1 strength is 106P2 skill is 100P2 strength is 101.
```

The zeros shouldn't be there.

Comment: Clearly `PlayerOneSkill + P1SkillMod` evaluates to `'102'`. Obviously your code contains bugs. Print out the values of all the raw variables and then you'll be able to find your mistake.

Comment: Can you show what `PlayerOneSkill` originally looks like? Before you convert it to a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xi Huan gave you the reason for why your code what what it was. The better way to do this would be:

```
f.write ("P1 skill is {0}".format( PlayerOneSkill + P1SkillMod))
```

Using the `format` function for strings. The `+` operator is highly inefficient. This would also make adding new lines for each player easier:

```
f.write ("P1 skill is {0}\n".format( PlayerOneSkill + P1SkillMod))  # New line added.
```

Answer (score 1):

Say `PlayerOneSkill` is `10`. Now you convert it to the string `'10'`.
Say the result of `P1SkillRoll12/P1SkillRoll4` is `2`. You also convert it to a string `'2'`.

Then you concatenate these strings (`'10'` and `'2'`), which will result in `'102'`.

*If you want to do integer arithmetik, you should use integers (true for any other numerical type).*

So you're looking for something like

```
# use numerical types here, not strings
skill = PlayerOneSkill + P1SkillRoll12/P1SkillRoll4 

# or use any other string formating
f.write("P1 skill is " + str(skill))
```

Comment: Yes. I understand. Strings are not suitable.